# Converting a const string into an array of ints?

Tags: c++

Hello I am trying to convert a const character string into an array of ints but when I try it does not allow it. My code is:

```
int isRegistered(const char str[]) {

int isbnInt[10], i;
//char isbnArray[10];

//isbnArray = str;  ----> something I tried

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    isbnInt[i] = atoi(str[i]);
    cout << isbnInt[i] << endl;
}
}
```

But when I try to compile it, I get an error saying "invalid conversion from char to const char*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atoi` call expects a `const char *` arguement, while you pass a `char`, this is the problem.

You can just do the below to convert the character to number. This subtracts the ascii value of `0` from the character itself ( since 0-9 are sequentially increasing in the ascii code.)

```
isbnInt[i] = str[i] - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    isbnInt[i] = str[i] - '0';
    cout << isbnInt[i] << endl;
}
```

[atoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) takes `const char*` as input instead of single char.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could also be written:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    char foo = str[i];
    isbnInt[i] = atoi(foo);
    cout << isbnInt[i] << endl;
}
```

Which won't work (as you've found); atoi expects a char*, not a char.

Try:

```
 int isbm = atoi(str);
```

and see if that does what you wanted.